# MongoJsonSchema.builder() does not generate SchemaMap with same specification as MongoDB CSFLE extended JSON Schema

Tags: mongodb, encryption, spring-data-mongodb

I am trying to implement Automatic Client-Side Field Level Encryption (CSFLE) in MongoDB (Enterprize Edition). The steps provided in [MongoDB Docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/use-cases/client-side-field-level-encryption-guide) work perfectly fine. However, `spring-data-mongodb` provides a way to generate $jsonSchema using MongoJsonSchema.builder() class to avoid writing the schema in raw JSON.

The problem that I am facing is that the schema generated by `MongoJsonSchem.builder()` differs from the specification mentioned and the example provided in MongoDB Docs [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mongodb/docs-assets/DOCSP-json-schema-helper-and-json/MedcoMDSchema.json).
To be specific, the example has

```
"keyId": [
      {
        "$binary": {
          "base64": "<paste_your_key_id_here>",
          "subType": "04"
        }
      }
    ]
```

but the schema generated by builder has

```
"keyId": [
            {
              "$binary": "<base64 encoded uuid>",
              "$type": "03"
            }
          ]
```

The execution fails only because the format of the key is not what the driver expects.

Unfortunately, the `EncryptedJsonSchemaProperty` only has `keyId()` that accepts a string and a `keys()` that accepts an array of UUIDs. Both of the methods generate schema that doesn't match with the example.

Is there anything that I am missing or is the builder not meant to be used to generate a `SchemaMap` that could be supplied to `AutoEncryptionSettings` as yet.

Comment: I created [DATAMONGO-2515](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-2515) to investigate the issue.

Comment: Thanks @ChristophStrobl! However, I just figured out that MongoJsonSchemaBuilder is working just fine. It was the conversion to BsonDocument that was converting the UUID type 4 to the type 3 representation while converting the Document. There seems to be no issues with the builder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, the problem was not at all in MongoJsonSchemaBuilder. It builds the schema just fine. It was the conversion to BsonDocument that was converting the UUID to version 3 representation. `AutoEncryptionSettings` needs BsonDocument for `schemaMap()`.

Finally, I had to supply in a `CodecRegistry` with `UuidCodec` with `STANDARD` representation of UUID. Also had to build the MongoClient with this codec registery and things worked just fine.

Sample code:

```
final CodecRegistry codecRegistry = 
                CodecRegistries.fromRegistries(CodecRegistries.fromCodecs(new UuidCodec(STANDARD)), getDefaultCodecRegistry());
final BsonDocument document = schema.toDocument().toBsonDocument(BsonDocument.class, codecRegistry).getDocument("$jsonSchema");
```

This was finally supplied to `AutoEncryptionSettings.builder().schemaMap()`

A full sample of the code is here: https://github.com/nishkarsh/mongodb-auto-csfle-demo

Answer (score 1):

The `$type` syntax is legacy extended json and is described [here](https://github.com/mongodb/specifications/blob/master/source/extended-json.rst#binary). In theory whatever is parsing the extended json should be capable of understanding both formats (`$subtype` and `$type` varieties).

The UUID types have recently been standardized [here](https://github.com/mongodb/specifications/blob/master/source/uuid.rst). There is no automatic conversion possible from type 3 to type 4 because there are multiple different implementations that use type 3 but store bytes in different order. So this needs to be fixed on the producing side.

I do not write Java myself but hopefully this helps identify where things are going wrong.